# How do I get the creator of a storage account in Azure?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage

I have a `StorageManagementClient` object authenticated with a service account. How do I get the creators of storage accounts listed in `storage_client.storage_accounts.list()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I get the creator of a storage account in Azure?

The creator of a storage account is not directly exposed by the Azure Storage service. There isn't any creator-specific attribute in the storage account resource directly. A specific way to obtain the creator information isn't provided by the Storage Management API, which gets used by the **`StorageManagementClient`** in the Azure SDK for Python.

If you need to get the creator using Python while creating a storage account you need to add the tag with **`CreatedBy:venkat`** once you added it, you can retrieve it with tags.

**Code:**

```
 from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.storage import StorageManagementClient

subscription_id = ""

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
storage_client = StorageManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

# Get the storage account properties
storage_account = storage_client.storage_accounts.list()
for storageaccount in storage_account:
    print(storageaccount.name)
    print(storageaccount.tags)
```

**Output:**
[image]

Alter, you can use the log analytic workspace to get the logs who **`Creates or update the storage account`** by using below query.

**Query:**

```
AzureActivity
|where OperationName == "Create/Update Storage Account"
|where OperationNameValue == "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/write"
|where ActivityStatus == "Succeeded"
|project Caller, ResourceId
```

**Output:**
[image]

> Note: **Limitation:** Activity Log has a fixed retention period of **90 days**

**Reference:**
[How can I get a report of who created resources in Azure Analytics? - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/759837/how-can-i-get-a-report-of-who-created-resources-in)